# Can somebody explain Strange behaviour of routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I develop my first project on `Laravel` and i faced strange behavior with routes. For example, I call my project `22y1`, so it's location would be `www/22y1` (there is a lot of different folders, don't use virtual hosts). From the web I reach it like `http://localhost/22y1`. My project will consist of the modules, so currently link looks like this `http://localhost/22y1/public/22y1` as i developing first module. When i trying to reach some route, like `http://localhost/22y1/public/22y1/time/last_24/` it redirects me to `http://localhost/22y1/time/last_24`. The main thing about this is that if i remove last slash, like this `http://localhost/22y1/public/22y1/time/last_24` it work ok, but with slash it do redirect... So may be someone could tell me from where this redirect comes ?

Comment: How's your `route.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Laravel 4.1+, try to edit `public/.htaccess` file, then remove this following line:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or, if you are using Laravel 4.0, edit `bootstrap/start.php`, remove this line:

```
$app->redirectIfTrailingSlash();
```